# What are the rules for using to-infinitives?

Tags: infinitives

Okay so let's start with verbs and to-infinitives. For example:
**This tool is used for opening ** or **This tool is used to open**
Which would be correct and why? I know that the to-infinitives are used to show the purpose of something and someone's opinion about something. But for is actually used for the same thing Isn't it? 
For example:
**I've got something for reading** and **I've got something to read**
I've been told that the first one sounds unnatural. But how do you determine this? I just can't understand it.

Comment: "This tool is used *for opening*" implies the purpose of the tool, while "This tool is used *to open*" implies an action actually taken.

Answer (score 2):

There are not general rules (or if there are, they are so weak as to be nearly useless).

Most of the time it is a matter of what kind of complement the particular head-word (verb, adjective, noun etc) requires, and I'm afraid that is simply a matter of learning.

So *used* can take either a to-infinitive clause or *for* followed by a noun phrase (which can be a gerund phrase).

*Happy*, on the other hand, can take a to-infinitive clause (*I'm happy to try it*), or *about* with a noun phrase (*I'm happy about the result*), but not *for* with a noun phrase (not **I'm happy for trying it*) - except for the variant of a to-infinitive clause where the subject is expressed with *for*: *I'm happy for him to try it*.

*Up* is commonly used in speech to mean *willing, ready*, and can take *for* with a noun phrase, but not a to-infinitive clause: *I'm up for leaving now*, but not **I'm up to leave now*.

Comment: What about when they are used with nouns? For example: "I am looking for toys to play with" and "I am looking for toys for playing" Are both correct here?

Comment: "Toys for playing" sounds really odd. "Nouns for X-ing" usually means "nouns that are to be X-ed", so "clothes for washing" is natural, In appropriate context (eg we're moving house) "I'm looking for toys for packing" would not be odd.

Comment: So If I tell somebody "Do you know resources for learning Spanish?" this literally means that the resources are to be learned?

Comment: @BoSsYyY: No. _Resources_ can take a _for_ complement. So I was wrong in limiting my original statement to verbs and adjectives. I'll edit it.